# Does airflow also increase in velocity as it hits a surface as fluid does?

Tags: aerodynamics

When you drop a stream of water to the ground, you can see it spreading out over a large area at a higher speed than it fell as the water thins out against the surface. Air is like fluid in many ways, but it doesn't hold itself together with polar/hydrogen bonds and tends to create turbulence and eddies more readily.

So, does a mass of air also experience this phenomena of spreading out faster that it was previously traveling as it hits a surface? Not necessarily a large surface, it could be a small sphere traveling fast through the air or a large surface like the ground or a mountain. You could argue conservation of energy or that it is specific to falling, which I'm not opposed to, but I also don't want to assume air is completely like fluid and that there could be some other mechanism at work.

Answer (score 0):

Air is as much a fluid as water. Both liquids (which I assume you mean by the term fluid) and gases are described by the same physical laws. Obviously, there are quantitative differences, but the qualitative features are the same.

The two examples you mentioned of polarity and hydrogen bonds are also present in gases. Only in the ideal gas model do we neglect those interactions - real gases behave very differently!

This deviation from ideality can be described by the so called compressibility factor. If you look up this Z-factor for the polar molecule NH3 and compare it to CO2, you will see that ammonia behaves much less ideal and that is partly caused by it's polarity, although there are also a lot of other intermolecular forces to be taken into account. HF is a great example for the influence of hydrogen bonds in the gaseous state.

By including more and more of these factors, you end up with more 'refined' models for the behaviour of gases. Look up the Van der Waals Equation, which extends the ideal gas model to include attractive and repulsive forces and gives a much more accurate description especially when you start to think about phase transitions between liquid and gas.

No you cant argue that conservation of energy is specific to falling. Neither is conservation of momentum.

Just think what would happen if the opposite were true and air behaves differently than water when hitting a surface, and therefore decrease or keep its initial velocity. Would planes be able to fly?

One of the key differences between the two in daily life is incompressibility. Water is compressible, but about 4 orders of magnitude less than air so this is a fair assumption in most cases. However, very interesting things happen if a flowing medium is viewed as compressible:

Consider a huge storage tank of an ideal gas at some higher than ambient pressure. Imagine drilling a small hole into the tank.

If the tank contained (incompressible) water, the water would flow out of the tank and thereby reduce it's pressure to ambient conditions. As the pressure of the water decreases, it's velocity increases.

Now that the tank contains an ideal gas, we have to take compressibility into account. It turns out there is a 'critical pressure' in the plane of the hole, and the gas can not reduce it's pressure lower than this critical pressure - so if the ambient pressure is lower than the critical, the exiting gas will reach the speed of sound and the only means to further reduce pressure is by shock.

Ever heard a military fighter jet transition into supersonice speed? The loud bang you hear is a result of this phenomenon. Google 'Schlieren Image', a very nice visualisation technique for supersonic shocks.