# Is there a conventional term for the phenomena of when fluids increase in speed after hitting the ground?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, aerodynamics, meteorology

Prompted by this question here that was near the top of the recent physics questions, [Does airflow also increase in velocity as it hits a surface as fluid does?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/414013/does-airflow-also-increase-in-velocity-as-it-hits-a-surface-as-fluid-does),

I simply wanted to ask about the term since I remember reading a phenomena similar to this in meteorology years ago when looking at descending air masses. I don't need any technical details, all I want to know is: what is the actual name of the phenomena outlined in this question where fluid-modeled substance that falls to the ground spreads out at a greater velocity? That could end up answering two question at once with a little bit of research too.

Comment: Water droplets falling to the ground generally come to a stop in a short distance. Under what circumstances do they increase in speed?

Comment: @D.Halsey The droplets do *eventually* slow down due to drag forces, but if you are familiar with physics, then I am sure you understand that *eventually* slowing down in no way means they couldn't have had a greater velocity at some earlier point in their trajectory. Allegedly, these droplets would increase in speed under the exact circumstance described in the question, after water hits the ground and *before* slowing down due the drag forces.